# Can't figure out source of mySQL syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working on a private messaging system between users on my site. Here's my query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO messages (to, `from`, message) VALUES ('{$user}', '{$username}', '{$message}')";
```

However, I get this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'to, `from`, message) VALUES ('Cheezey', 'Cheezey', 'Enter your message here')' at line 1
```

I have a nagging feeling that it's a really stupid error on my part, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `to` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html) in MYSQL, you have to put ` around it, like this:

```
 INSERT INTO(`to`, ...).
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it was. Accepting your answer when SO will let me.